# Liferay: How to minify CSS and JS file included in jsp

Tags: javascript, css, liferay, liferay-6.2

I am using multiple css and js files in one of my Liferay portlet. CSS and JS files included in liferay-portlet.xml file are automatically getting included in page.

Apart from files mentioned in XML file I am using external CSS and JS file using Link and Script tag.

How can I minify these files?

OR

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>demo-page</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/style.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
</portlet>
```

I want to use main.css in page1.jsp but not in page2.jsp.
Can I define page scope for files included in liferay-portlet.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You just use your file like for css: `< link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/my_sources/css/style.css"/>` and liferay takes care of minifying (unless you have disabled it in portal-ext.properties).

Comment: Its not working even if theme.css.fast.load value is true

Comment: That's pretty weired...have you tried adding cc_fast_load=1 as request parameter in your URL?

Comment: just referencing some random css in HTML does not make Liferay process that file. I'd recommend to add the CSS to the theme - it will marginally grow the theme's CSS (which will get minified) and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

In your portal-ext :

```
# Set this property to true to load the theme's merged CSS files for faster
# loading for production.
#
# Set this property to false for easier debugging for development. You can
# also disable fast loading by setting the URL parameter "css_fast_load" to
# "0".
#
theme.css.fast.load=true


# Set this property to true to load the packed version of files listed in
# the properties "javascript.barebone.files" or
# "javascript.everything.files".
#
# Set this property to false for easier debugging for development. You can
# also disable fast loading by setting the URL parameter "js_fast_load" to
# "0".
#
javascript.fast.load=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Liferay only minifiy the resource included inside themes and portlet adding it in liferay-portlet.xml. If you want to do this to all css and js file you should implement a hook for a Liferay Servlet Filter and inside the filter you can proccess any resource as you wish. The filter is executed in all request to external resources.

[image]